# Can't bind a button in a listview to ViewModel using ReactiveUI

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI to bind a button to ReactiveCommand but it doesn't response to  it , so what did I missed here??

this is the LikeCommand

```
     LikesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<Button>(LikeChanges);


private void LikeChanges(Button sender)
    {
        sender.Clicked += (s, e) =>
        {
            _newsFeed.LikesNum++;
            _newsFeed.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            _newsFeed.TextColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        };
    }
```

and this is the DeleteCommand

```
 DeleteCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<NewsFeed>(DeleteItem);

     public async void DeleteItem(NewsFeed news)
    {
        var res = await CoreMethods.DisplayAlert("OH !", "Are you sure?", 
                 "Yes", "No");
        if (res)
        {
            NewsFeeds.Remove(news);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }

    }
```

and this is my buttons in a viewCell in the list view

```
     <Button Text="{Binding LikesNum , StringFormat='Like {0}'}"
           x:Name="btnLike"
           Command="{Binding LikesCommand}"
           BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"
           TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <Button Text="Delete"
            x:Name="btnLike"
           Clicked="Button_OnClicked"
           Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
           HorizontalOptions="End" />
```

Comment: For one, remove the sender.Clicked delegate inside LikeChanges. ReactiveCommand takes care of the clicked event. You only need the content inside that lambda. Make your ReactiveCommand signature look like ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> LikesCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues.

The generic on the Create is for a command parameter but you haven't defined one. Often you'll bind the selected element to the view model instead.

The Create will is when you do the following:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Name=SelectedItem}" />
```

The T in Create matches up to the type you are passing in via the CommandParameter. The other way is on your ViewModel to have a property called SelectedItem on your ViewModel then bind the SelectedItem to that property.

You'd probably want {Binding DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay}

Avoid returning **async void**, do **public async Task** instead and use the CreateFromTask overload instead.

You have a clicked and a command on your button. You want one or the other.

See also 
https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/ for more ideas.

Also consider using reactiveui binding.

Comment: I also just pushed through some updated documentation that goes through a lot of this stuff just now. Give it 15 minutes and that Commands documentation will update.

Comment: sry but I'm new to ReactiveUI , can you explain more? 
I studied the commands in the documantations .. but about reactiveUI binding I tried to bind it this way :     this.BindCommand(new NewsFeedListPageModel(_databaseService), vm => vm.LikesCommand, ) and it's wrong. It's not taking the view as lambda third parameter.. can you write the right way for me? 
and for the Generics I'm passing my parameter of the button in the command so what's wrong here? thank you

Comment: Have a look at that page again. It's literally changed in the last minute or so and covers a lot of the issues you're having. Also edited it with more information.

Comment: Hmm also worth noting, you're LikeChanges is most likely wrong. The Command concept replaces the Click. So don't have a event handler in the LikeChanges method, and don't bother with passing in a button.

Comment: public override void Init(object initData)
        {
            base.Init(initData);
            NewsFeeds = new ObservableCollection<NewsFeed>(_databaseService.GetNewsFeeds());
            AddNewsFeedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<NewsFeedPageModel>());
            SelectedItemCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>(SelectedItemAction);
LikesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<Button>(LikeChanges)       DeleteCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<NewsFeed(DeleteItem);
the first three commands are executed well

Comment: Events != Commands. 

Commands should know nothing about controls so don't put in things like Buttons in there.

Commands also don't know about event args and all that stuff normally.

Avoid command Parameters, and therefore using the generic overload.